# DevExpress XtraEditors TextEdit mask

Tags: input, devexpress, mask, xtraeditors

I have a TextEdit and need to limit its input to the following type of formats:

- 00.000
- 0.000
- 00.00
- 0.00
- ...

There can be up to 3 decimal places. Integer part is not required.

The closest thing I've found is `MaskType = Numeric` with `###.###` mask. However, this doesn't accept all zeros, which is a requirement.

Any suggestions?

ADD: I'm thinking of `0{0,3}\.0{0,3}` with `MaskType = RegEx`. Is it a suitable choice?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've answered your own question.  Your RegEx looks fine.

If you meant to allow non-zero values too, such as 12.345 or 001.010, then the mask should be
`[0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{0,3}`.

Answer (score 0):

Check XtraEditor's [Mask Type: Numeric](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1498). you are setting wrong edit mask. on the place of `###.###` use `000.000`. Check the custom mask section on the specified link.

> In case of #, the input string is converted to the editor's value,
>   digits left empty are not stored in the result, but in case 0; the
>   digits left empty are interpreted as zeros.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = MaskType.Numeric;
            textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "000.000";
            textEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
        }
```